# Multi thread making it run all once

Tags: python, web3py, telebot

I really appreciate everyone who contributed to my first question though am new here If I didn't ask in a way you can understand do bear with me.

I have  a database and in it a table name contracts which the data in the rows are contract and group, i.e each each group has a single contract.

I need help so that once the bot is started it checks the database and list of contracts in it then it runs task for each group and their own contracts at same time...
This codes below is what I was able to work on but it just works for only one group

```
from web3 import Web3
import json,os,sys

import datetime

import requests
from db import *
import telebot


bot = telebot.TeleBot("Telegram bot api will be here")



 
bsc = "https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/"
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(bsc))




class BuyBot():
    def init(self,token,group):
        self.token = token
        self.group = group
        
    
    def main(self):
        print(f"EVENTS RUNNING FOR {self.token}")
        event_filter = web3.eth.filter({"address": web3.toChecksumAddress((self.token).upper()), "block_identifier": 'pending', })
        
        
        self.log_loop(event_filter, 2)
               
        
           
    def log_loop(self,event_filter, poll_interval):
        try:
            while True:
                for event in event_filter.get_new_entries():
                    self.handle_event(event)
                    break
                time.sleep(poll_interval)
        except Exception as p:
            print(p)
            self.main()
            
    def handle_event(self,event):
        txn = json.loads(Web3.toJSON(event))
        hash = txn['transactionHash']
    
        if len(hash) > 0:
            transaction_recipt = web3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(hash)
            trs = web3.toHex(transaction_recipt['transactionHash'])
            usl_hash = f"https://bscscan.com/tx/{trs}"
            bot.send_message(self.group,url_hash)


def main():
    while True:
        print("am here")
        con = bot_db()
        mc= con.cursor()
        mc.execute('SELECT * FROM Contracts')
        rows = mc.fetchall()
        for all in rows:
            group = all[1]
            ca = all[0]
            
            check_ = BuyBot(ca,group)
            check_.main()

bot.polling(none_stop=True)

if name == "main":
    try:
        print("Started")
        main()
    except Exception:
        print("rebooted")
        main()
```

Please do help I need it to listen to events on the Bsc chain web3 for each group at same time with each group contract.

As I stated below please do bear with me if you don't understand what I meant

Comment: I may not have understood your question but if you want literal running of two threads "at the exact same time" this is not possible because of how scheduling works with operating systems, which are responsible for managing thread execution. If I misunderstood your question please let me know.

Comment: You understood me so it's not possible anyhow to do that ?

Comment: Do you understand how operating systems manage threads in general? You might be able to find an overview on something like wikipedia. In general operating systems are not real time systems. It means that the precise timing of when threads execute cannot be controlled.

It might be there is a way to address your problem without this being a neccessary precondition however - but I did't understand enough detial from your question to be able to answer that.

Comment: I don't know how else to explain but let me try...

Comment: The main function checks the database. We have  a table named users, in it and each user has an ID and a contract address. So when the bot is started it runs the main function which checks the database and the user's contract and ID is sent to the class BuyBot, I want that it sends those data to class at same time, let's say we have two users in the database, and each user has its own contract I want the BuyBot.main() function to run at same time for each user

Comment: One basic question: Why do you need these things to run at the same time. Why does it not work as a single threaded application? Is it possible to build a working single threaded version and then change the code a where necessary to dispatch multiple threads?

Comment: Sorry I don't you ,but this is a telegram bot am trying to create so each group can add their project contract address then bot can check the events running on their contract and give them response. But with the codes I have it only works for one group and doesn't even run for the other group

Answer (score 0):

Was able to do what I needed multiprocessing did the job I needed ✅

Here is the documentation

https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).